# VisualstateManager in Style

Tags: silverlight, coding-style, state, visualstatemanager

I am new to both Silverlight and Blend 4.
I am trying to make a Image Gallery, where u click on the image and it shows details of the same. 
I used VisualStateManager to get a mouseOver and mouseOut effect to the thumbnails. and here is wat i want. I want to add the VisualState's to all my thumbnails through Style. (I had seen this in some forum, but i cudnt figure it out how he did it.)

Here is wat i want:

**I have set of thumbnails to, which need to scale up on MouseOver and come back to normal on MouseOUT. I created a VisualStateManager States.**

> **But i want to use the state as a
>   common state for all the thumbnails
>   and apply it to the thumbnails through
>   Style.**

Is this possible? If so how?

If not? then is how can i achieve it.

Would be really thankful to any one who can help me :) just that this is a bit urgent. :(

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) says that you should be able to add the VisualStageManager XAML tag to any control which inherits from UIElement and accepts child controls.

It seems to me then that the best way to do this is to create a UserControl for your thumbnail and set the VisualStateManager there. You can then reuse that UserControl.

More reading material:

- [MSDN UserControl documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)
- [Adding behaviour to stock controls](http://bryantlikes.com/BehaviorsVsSubclassingInSilverlight.aspx)

Comment: do u have a code for ths...?? i still dint get it... am just a newbee to silverlight ya...

Comment: I can try make something, but I'm up to my head in school work right now

Comment: I added some more links so you can get started, but I don't have the time to make some example code myself. You could check out my tumblr to read the [infinitely scrolling listbox tutorial](http://coderants.tumblr.com/post/2326195991/) pt. 1. I subclass the stock ListBox control there so it might give you an idea about how that works :)